# how to put the two input text fields on the same line through jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Actually i am fetching data from the Google Spread sheet which is saved from the client side. i want to put the two input fields on the same line.
Here is my piece of code which is appending the data in the div.

```js
$('#commentdiv').append(`<center>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="" 
  id="updateinput_${it}" value="${formData}" style="width:100%;"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</center>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="commentdiv"></div>
```

Please anyone can help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Pardeep Dhingra thankx for correction but complete piece of code is the part of jquery

Comment: No one is answering my question. Why?